# What's the difference between a CUC union of countable sets and a countable union of CUC sets?

Tags: set-theory

Let's assume no choice at all and write CUC as a countable union of countable sets (which may not be countable). I'm interested in comparing a CUC union of countable sets and a countable union of CUC sets.

Of course, a CUC union of countable sets is a countable union of CUC sets: let $\bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1} I_i$ be a CUC, then $\bigcup_{j\in \bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1} I_i} A_j = \bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1} \bigcup_{j\in I_i} A_j$. What about the converse? And, if possible, are there more can be said about these two kinds of sets? Thanks advance for your help.

Comment: I'm confused by your terminology, so just to clarify: Suppose we have a union $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$. This is "A CUC union of countable sets" if $I$ is a countable union of countable sets, and each $A_i$ is countable. On the other hand, this is "a countable union of CUC sets" if $I$ is countable, and each $A_i$ is a countable union of countable sets. Is that right?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, that's what I mean. Thanks!

Comment: What does CUC stand for?

Comment: @user3257842 Sorry, but I believe that I wrote in the question that CUC is "a countable union of countable sets" :)